# Is pre-processing necessary when i use spaCy NER?

Tags: nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm using spaCy NER for the very basic function of extracting names, the strings I'm entering are under 600 characters. I was wondering if I really need to remove stopwords and junk characters.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCOQX.png)

I'm able to extract the name with no problem, and I've tried with multiple names and they all work, so do I really have to do pre-processing?

Comment: The best way to answer your question is to try several preprocessing pipelines and see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Especially the part which says: "DO NOT post images of code".

Comment: @zabop, i had read it and i thought i had given sufficient information before sharing the code. Sorry, will try to elaborate more next time.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov thankyou, i did try it. Looks like removing the junk words doesn't make much of a noticeable difference

Comment: The problem is that you are not posting code, but a link to an image showing code. Post the code itself. If having trouble, look at some other questions how they do it.

Comment: Okay, will do, thankyou